# Finding the length of a list after filtering a previous list in Python / Store list in a variable after filtering

Tags: python

I am just starting to code in Python so please be aware of my inexperience.

I am working on a project where I get a list of stores in an excel file with the tab names. However there is a bit of "trash" in this list:

`tab_list = ['store1', 'trash1', 'store2', 'trash2', 'store3', ...]`

After using the filter() function, I have:

`clean = filter(lambda x: x not in trash_list, tab_list)`

after looking at other questions like this, to output the final cleaned list I have to first transform it into a list so I have:

`list(clean)`  that outputs me the right ['store1', 'store2', 'store3', ...] free of the trash.

My problem is that I would like to store this cleaned list in a variable (a list) so that I can iterate on it.
When I do `len(list(clean))` it returns 0. Hence, I have not been able to iterate over this cleaned list of stores.

How can I store this list somewhere where I can iterate over it?
Why does len(list(clean)) output 0 when clearly when I just put list(clean) the list is 10 elements long?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Montaigne

Comment: `clean = list(filter(lambda x: x not in trash_list, tab_list))`

Comment: The return value of `filter` is an iterator. Iterators can only be iterated over once. `list(clean)` does that. After that `clean` is empty. You could've put the result of `list(clean)` in a variable as well.

Comment: You can also directly iterate through the filter object (`clean` in your example).

Comment: @rdas You found the solution! Thank you very much! How can I "upvote" your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filter` returns an iterator and when you do `list(..)` on it, you iterate over it and it is exhausted. When you again run `list(..)` on it, it has now nothing to give back, hence `len` giving 0.

Remedy is to assign it to a variable when first iterated:

```
clean = list(filter(lambda x: x not in trash_list, tab_list))
```

But I'd say [a list comprehension is better](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196):

```
clean = [item
         for item in tab_list
         if item not in trash_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the generator `clean` is depleted, it becomes empty. You should work with the `list(clean)` from that point on instead.

```
generator = filter(...)
A = list(generator)  # has items
B = list(generator)  # empty
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way too

```
tab_list = ['store1', 'trash1', 'store2', 'trash2', 'store3']
store_list = [item for item in tab_list if 'trash' not in item]
```